# create multiple classes with wxFormBuilder for python

Tags: oop, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I'm using wxFormBuilder to write a series of GUI applications. So far it has worked wonderfully, but the documentation on their homepage is a broken link.

What I'd like to do is combine my programs into one program, each as a different tab in a wxNotebook. However, I can only get wxFormBuilder to generate one class, the class for my frame. Ideally, what I'd like is for each panel to be its own class, so then I can override each class individually, and not be stuck with one giant class which contains all the event handlers for 5 different applications.

Is this possible with wxFormBuilder? Is there a different program which would allow me to do this more easily?

I'm open to other wx programs, but can't departure from Python, and I'd really rather not have to write the wx code by hand.

Comment: If all else fails: A simple class like that (just aggregating other widgets) shouldn't be *too* difficult to do by hand.

Comment: My real reluctance to that is not  fear of spinning it by hand. It's really easy to adapt the code outputted from wxFormBuilder, but it's the fact that I'd have to redo it every time I made a change to the layout. But, when all else fails, that might just be what I have to do. thanks!

Comment: I just ran into the same problem - is there still no way for this in wxFormBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Some people like wxGlade, Boa Constructor (old) or XRCed (included with wxPython). You might experiment with those. I've heard good things about wxFormBuilder, so I'm a little surprised it doesn't have that capability. Here are some links: http://www.oneminutepython.com/

http://sturlamolden.blogspot.com/2008/03/howto-using-wxformbuilder-with-wxpython.html

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/11/wxpython-an-introduction-to-xrc/

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks! I get the impression wxFormBuilder is great because it's simple and it works well, but once you start getting into more complicated stuff, it's not quite sophisticated enough to keep up.

Comment: None of the wxPython building utilities have all the custom widgets included. But they can help in organizing your code and figuring out the basics. I hand code all mine though.